# Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: кодировка, php

Парсер на выходе дает текст с такой кодировкой

```
Ïèñüìî ÊÖ ïî öåíîîáðàçîâàíèþ è ñìåòíîìó íîðìèðîâàíèþ â ñòðîèòåëüñòâå îò 14.10.2013 ã. ¹ ÊÖ/Ï2013-10òè Îá èíäåêñàõ èçìåíåíèÿ ñìåòíîé ñòîèìîñòè ñòðîèòåëüñòâà ïî îêðóãàì è ðåãèîíàì ÐÔ íà îêòÿáðü 2013 ã.
```

Дескриптор Лебедева говорит что это CP1251

Я попытался поменять кодировку используя например вот эту функцию, но теперь там просто знаки вопроса.

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($page_title, "CP1251", "CP1252");
```

Как лучше мне сделать дескрипт?

Comment: а зачем вы с cp1252 то переделываете ?

    mb_convert_encoding($page_title, "CP1251", "UTF8");

Comment: c utf8 тоже в знаки вопроса переводит

Comment: ребята, а вас не смущает то, что второй аргумент - это **выходная** кодировка?

Comment: тогда как правильно сделать перевод?

Comment: @HappyCougar, если залезть в доки, то можно увидеть, что надо просто поменять аргументы местами. Если тогда не будет работать - обратиться к iconv.

Comment: @Fike, а что где-то ещё cp1251 как кодировка сайта используется ?

В смысле меня не смущает, что кодировка должна получиться utf8

Comment: @eicto, в вашем примере текст из utf8 перегоняется в cp1251. Потому что второй аргумент - то, во что строка кодируется, а третий - из чего.

Comment: Что-то как-то не работает, ни iconv, ни mb_convert_encodin

Comment: http://toster.ru/q/15281 нашел решение здесь

Comment: Так а где вы получили такой вывод? В броузере? Если да, то какая кодировка на странице? А откуда данные парсите: из файла или из ДБ или мот еще откуда-то?